# Private file for an app

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography

I would like to create a file which stores some data that can be accessed only by my app.Outside users should not be able to access this file or make any changes to it.I will store a key in the file which maybe accessed by the app whenever needed.

Comment: what is your question then????

Comment: @KKD what's with the quadruple question marks? i believe the asker is clear about wanting to know where he should store the data to a private location accessible only by his application.

Comment: Sorry.... Should have mentioned in the question. (please don't ask about quadruple full stops.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an application private file (that is not readable by other applications) you should use [Context.openFileOutput()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) with a flag [MODE_PRIVATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE).

If you are concerned you could wrap the returned InputStream in [CiperOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream.html) and encrypt the contents.

If you are storing keys in a standard crypto format (X.509 or PKCS#12) you could use the new [KeyChain](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html) API introduced in ICS.

Answer (score 3):

Use Environment.getDataDirectory(),
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getDataDirectory()

This gives a File object that is the path to a private, app specific data directory. The files created therein are owned by your app's user ID, preventing any other app from accessing them.

```
File myPrivateFile = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory(), context.getPackageName() + File.separator + "secret.txt");
```

Note that if the device is rooted, all bets are off. A root process can read any file on the device. The best you can do is only store information for user of the device. That way if it's compromised, only one user account is compromised. In other words, don't store credentials, keys, access tokens, etc. That would allow a malicious agent access to a server where it could steal data for other users.

Comment: For more information on Android security, see here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html

Comment: Not true, Environment.getDatDirectory returns the data directory for Android (typically /data/data). This is NOT app specific.

Comment: @NicStrong , can this be accessed outside my app i.e maybe by using an application like file browser?

Comment: nic, you are right. you must qualify that further with the app-specific data directory. i've updated the answer.

Comment: @Ani, no it cannot, not as i've updated above. this is the same place app preferences and database files are stored. you can test this by getting a non-rooted phone and trying to browser into that folder with a file browser or terminal app.

Comment: @farble1670 , thanks a lot for your answer. I will try it out on my app as soon as possible

Comment: @farble1670 that would work but is still not 100% guaranteed (e.g. if the user wanted the app to be moved to the sd card). The safest way is to use to use Context.getDir(String name, int mode) which would usually return a path of /data/data/packagename/files/dirname.

Comment: @Nic moving the app to the SD card does not move all components of the app, just certain resources. i don't know for certain that it does not move the data, but i suspect not. that being said, you are right, getting the file or stream from the Context seems like the right solution. i've used my solution with success, but there's clearly a well-defined interface for doing the same thing so that should be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just stored it in a [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) ??

Make your `SharedPreference` private to your activity by calling..

```
getSharedPreferences(yourfile, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

This will make sure only your `Activity` can access that `SharedPreference`.

Comment: because he asked about storing a file, not a key-value pair.

Comment: Also, SharedPreference can also be accessed with root access.

Answer (score 1):

To open a file from a private app folder, one can use this file path:

```
File myFilePath = new File(getContext().getFilesDir() + File.separator + "myFile")
```

You can check if the file exists `if(myFilePath.exists())` ...

To save a text file to the private app directory

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
   fos = getContext().openFileOutput("myFile",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) { }

try {
   fos.write(myTextString.getBytes());
} catch (IOException e) { }

try {
   fos.close();
} catch (IOException e) { }
```

To save an image to the private app directory:

```
try {
  myBitmapImage.compress(CompressFormat.JPG, 90, 
                                   openFileOutput("myimage.jpg", MODE_PRIVATE));
} catch (Exception e) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to store an encrypted file and decrypt it run-time, so even a rooted phone would not be able to read your data even if it has access to it. Of course, it's a chicken-egg condition (where would you store your key for the encrypted file), and the only thing better than putting the key in a variable is to generate that key runtime using some obscure method (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity))